# Can I declare the property value in an ant target and use this value into another target?

Tags: java, ant

I am pretty new in Ant and I have the following doubt:

If I declare a **property** in a specific target, for example this:

```
<target name="initUnixPath" if="unix">
    <echo message="initUnixPath: SETTING UNIX PATH" />
    <property name="path">/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/</property>
</target>
```

In a second time (in another target) can I use the path named property and initialized in the initUnixPath target?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: I guess you can make the second target "depends" on the first target that has the property defined. Then use the property in the second target.

Answer (score 1):

you can make the second target "depends" on the first target that has the property defined. Then use the property in the second target.

```
    <project default="child">
      <target name="child" depends="parent">
        <property name="firstname" value="Reji"/>
        <echo>${firstname}</echo>
        <echo>${lastname}</echo>
      </target>
      <target name="parent">
        <property name="lastname" value="Nair"/>
      </target>
    </project>
```